# I have two points in my geodjango models when serializing them using drf gis one of them gets renamed and the renamed one doesn't show in haystack?

Tags: postgis, geodjango

```python
class Space(TimeStampedModel):
    origin = models.PointField()
    destination = models.PointField()
    origin_address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    destination_adress = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class SpaceSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Space
        geo_field = 'origin'
        geo_field ='destination'
        id = False
        fields = (
            'id',
            'origin',
            'destination',
            'origin_address',
            'destination_adress',
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can not specify two `geo_fields` the way you did in your example. The geo field there is a class property, you can not specify two with the same name. So the second one will override the first one (its a class property). The reason is that the geo-serializer will try to construct a geojson layer, which creates a list of features. This list will be a list of points in your case.

So if you don't need the geojson output, you could just use a normal serializer and return four float fields lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2.

For this to work as geojson output, you probably have to construct a MultiPoint Geometry collection. And then pass that object to the serializer.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#multipoint